# Interface or enum expected

Tags: java

I am attempting to complete a simple exercise where 2 fighter objects are sent to a function and you work out which one dies first based on their properties. Here is my code below:

```
public class Kata {
  public static String declareWinner(Fighter fighter1, Fighter fighter2, String firstAttacker) {
    // Your code goes here. Have fun!
    Fighter firstFighterToAttack = fighter1;
    Fighter secondFighterToAttack = fighter2;

    if (fighter2.name.equals(firstAttacker)) {
      return fight(fighter2, fighter1);
    } else {
      return fight(fighter1, fighter2);
    }

    private static String fight(Fighter firstFighterToAttack, Fighter secondFighterToAttack) {
        secondFighterToAttack.health -= firstFighterToAttack.damagePerAttack;
        while(true) {
          if(secondFighterToAttack.health <= 0) {
            return firstFighterToAttack.name;
          } 
           firstFighterToAttack.health -= secondFighterToAttack.damagePerAttack;
          if(firstFighterToAttack.health < 1)
            return secondFighterToAttack.name;
          }
        }   
      }    
    }
}
```

I am getting a compiler error saying

```
: /Kata.java:26: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}^
```

Does anyone have any idea why  it wants an interface or enum? I can't seem to work it out

Comment: you never close the function with a `}`

Comment: You cannot declare a function (`private static String fight(...)`) inside another function (`upblic static String declareWinner(...)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the declaration of the `fight()` method inside the `declareWinner()` method. They should be declared at the same level, directly inside the `Kata` class.

```
public class Kata {
    public static String declareWinner(Fighter fighter1, Fighter fighter2, String firstAttacker) {
        return fighter2.name.equals(firstAttacker)
            ? fight(fighter2, fighter1)
            : fight(fighter1, fighter2);
    }

    private static String fight(Fighter firstFighterToAttack, Fighter secondFighterToAttack) {
        ... // fight logic
    }
}
```

Just as an aside, proper indenting will help you spot problems like this. Your editor/IDE almost certainly has a "format code" command somewhere; I use mine religiously and it's saved me lots of grief.

P.S. The reason for the error message (which I agree is confusing) is that it *is* legal to define a class, interface, or enum inside a function. Such things are not common, but they are useful on occasion. The compiler probably saw the `private static` part of the `fight` declaration and complained because following those two keywords in a method, the only legal things that can follow are a class, interface, or enum definition. See the Java tutorial segment on [Local Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) for more details and some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You just had some problems with your closing bracket } that's all. I formatted it for you, see if you are still having problem.

```java
public class Kata {
    public static String declareWinner(Fighter fighter1, Fighter fighter2, String firstAttacker) {
        // Your code goes here. Have fun!
        Fighter firstFighterToAttack = fighter1;
        Fighter secondFighterToAttack = fighter2;

        if (fighter2.name.equals(firstAttacker)) {
            return fight(fighter2, fighter1);
        } else {
            return fight(fighter1, fighter2);
        }
    }

    private static String fight(Fighter firstFighterToAttack, Fighter secondFighterToAttack) {
        secondFighterToAttack.health -= firstFighterToAttack.damagePerAttack;
        while(true) {
            if(secondFighterToAttack.health <= 0) {
                return firstFighterToAttack.name;
            }
            firstFighterToAttack.health -= secondFighterToAttack.damagePerAttack;
            if(firstFighterToAttack.health < 1)
                return secondFighterToAttack.name;
        }
    }
}
```